# Did Swedes dominate Counter Strike and Counter Strike Global Offensive for years and why?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike, competitive-gaming

Did Swedish/Scandinavian teams dominate international tournaments in Counter Strike and Counter Strike Global Offensive for years? Given a population of 10/24 million inhabitants, I would assume that they should not be able to compete succesfully with the rest of the world for longer periods. Two points in favour of the Swedes and maybe Danes might be that a considerable part of their population lived close to their capital with very good internet connections (100Mbit around year 2000). Other factors might be evenly distributed wealth (so more people have/had computers) and a higher propensity to spend your time inside when Winters are cold. So, if Swedish/Scandinavian teams dominate(d) international tournaments in CS and CSGO, why did they? Are there other factors than the ones I mentioned?